# GWTP - Am I using it correctly for secured and unsecured areas?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I am trying to do a transition to GWTP with my already existing application. However, I am having some troubles figuring out how to have a secured and an unsecured area for it.

The case is simple: I am having a landing page and an admin page which both have entirely different skeletons (menu, side nav, main content, etc.).

To make it simpler, these are my current module implementations:

[image]

What I am actually having in my `ApplicationView` UiBinder is this:

which is a public static UI field of `ApplicationView`:

```java
public static @UiField SimplePanel mainContentWrapper;
```

What I do now is setting the actual content inside of the `onReveal()` method of the two presenter `AdminToolPresenter` and `LangingPresenter` like this:

```java
@Inject
AdminToolPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy, ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_AdminMainContent);
}

@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();
    ApplicationView.mainContentWrapper.setWidget(this.getView());
}
```

and

```java
@Inject
LandingPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy, ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_LandingMainContent);
}

@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();
    ApplicationView.mainContentWrapper.setWidget(this.getView());
}
```

Please note how I bind `ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_AdminMainContent` and `ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_LandingMainContent` respectively.

Since GWTP is actually a pretty smart tool I want to make sure that I am using it correctly.

Therefore I'd like to know if I do this the way it is intended to be or if GWTP actually provides a smarter solution to this problem?

This question rises especially since I am not sure yet how navigation is actually going to be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to call `ApplicationView.mainContentWrapper.setWidget(this.getView())` in your `onReveal` method.
`GWTP` should take care of that either by using `bindSlot(ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_LandingMainContent, mainContentWrapper)` in your `ApplicationView` constrcutor or by overriding the `setInSlot` or `addToSlot` method in your `ApplicationView`. (see the [SLOTS documentation](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/core/slots/))

You will also want to use a [Gatekeeper](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/tutorials/tutorial-part2.html) to secure your `AdminToolPresenter`.

Comment: I think what I actually want is some sort of "root" slot in which either the LandingPresenter or the AdminToolPresenter can life.

Comment: In my ApplicationPresenter I guess there should be a `SLOT_Root` but I don't know how I can make the other two presenters to reveal themselve inside that slot.

Comment: Just call `bindSlot(ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_Root,mainContentWrapper)` in the constructor of your `ApplicationView` and use that SLOT also in the `AdminToolPresenter` and `LandingPagePresenter`. Depening on the URL they right `Presenter` should reveal itself there.